# Selecting all children and decendants with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML that is being produced by a WordPress plugin that is designed to allow for expandable/collapsible text, with up to three levels of depth. I would like it so that if you were to collapse the first or second levels and the children below it were also expanded those too would get collapsed but nothing I use seems to allow the selection of *all* children. This is what I'm using so far:

```
$(".hidden-text-toggle").click(function () {
    if ($(".hidden-text:animated").length) return false;
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        if ($(this).hasClass('expanded') ){     
            $(this).removeClass('expanded');
            $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "black" , color: "red"});    
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('expanded');
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "red" , color: "black"});

        }
        return false;
    });

<div class="wrapper">
    <h2 class="title">Level One</h2>
    <div class="text" href="#">
        This is level one text.
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h2 class="title" href="#">Level Two</h2>
            <div class="text">
                This is level two text.
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <h2 class="title" href="#">Level Three</h2>
                    <div class="text">                          
                        This is level three text. 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would have thought that putting something like `$(this).find(".text").slideUp();` after line 4 would allow this but apparently I am wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your JavaScript is targeting `.hidden-text-toggle`, but I don't see this class being used in your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do a blanket *slideUp* on every element (do this in combination with *[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)*):

```
$("div.wrapper").find("div").slideUp();
```

Note that this is essentially selecting every *div* underneath the root node, then animating the height of each to zero.  Any elements that are already zero height will not be affected.

Comment: Thanks. Using this I found that adding `(this).parent().find("div").not(".wrapper").slideUp();
$(this).parent().find("h2").removeClass('expanded');` inside the first bit of the if statement managed to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("h2.title").click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/amppK/

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/